# Go - Variable initialized and non nil, but nil for other functions

Tags: go, initialization, global-variables

It's a bit hard to write a title that match with my current problem..
I have a main() function which uses a function in another package (database_sql). This function initializes a global variable sql.DB*. After the initialization, the variable isn't nil, but for the others functions, this variable is still nil.. Let see the code below !

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    db "./database_sql"
    router "./router"
)

func main() {

    db.Init_SQL();

    router.Init_routes()

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router.GetRouter())

}
```

db.go

```
package database_sql

import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

var DB *sql.DB // global variable to share it between main and the HTTP handler                                                                                                                              
//var dbi *databaseinfos                                                                                                                                                                                     

func Init_SQL() {
    dbi := databaseinfos{
            user: "something",
            password: "something",
            name: "something",
            address: "something",
            port: "2323",
            url: ""}
    dbi.url = (dbi.user + ":" + dbi.password + "@tcp(" + dbi.address + ":" + dbi.port + ")/" + dbi.name)

    db_init_var, err := sql.Open("mysql", dbi.url)
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error on initializing database connection: %s", err.Error())
    }

    err = db_init_var.Ping()
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error on opening database connection: %s", err.Error())
    }

    // Here, as you can test, my variable is initialized
    if err == nil {
            DB = db_init_var
            if DB == nil {
                    fmt.Println("NIL DB !!")
            }
            if db_init_var == nil {
                    fmt.Println("NIL db_init_var !!")
            }
            fmt.Println(dbi.url)
    }
}
```

Now, everything is ok ! I will now test http://xxxxxxx/login with an username/password. Everything's working fine and now, it's the time to make a request in the database with my DB variable declared above.

request_user.go

```
package database_sql

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    m "models"
)

func CanLogin(user m.User) (bool, m.User, m.StatusBack) {

    // Prepare statement for reading data                                                                                                                                                                
    stmtOut, err := DB.Prepare("SELECT username, password, token FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?")
    if err != nil {
            return false, user, m.StatusBack{ToString: err.Error(), IdStatus: http.StatusInternalServerError}
    }
defer stmtOut.Close()

    // Query the user                                                                                                                                                                                    
err = stmtOut.QueryRow(user.Username, user.Password).Scan(&user.Username, &user.Password, &user.UUID) // WHERE user is registered                                                                    
    if err != nil {
            return false, user, m.StatusBack{ToString: "User not found.", IdStatus: http.StatusNotFound}
    } else {

            j, err := json.Marshal(user)
            if err == nil {
                    return true, user, m.StatusBack{ToString: string(j), IdStatus: http.StatusOK}
            } else {
                    return false, user, m.StatusBack{ToString: err.Error(), IdStatus: http.StatusInternalServerError}
    }
    }

}
```

However, when I'm making my sql request, the following line says that DB is nil.
**stmtOut, err := DB.Prepare("SELECT username, password, token FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?")**

I made lot of test such as trying to initialize it with '=' and no ':='. I tried 'if DB == nil' statement and DB is always nil.. Why? I initialize my database var before initialize my router, so technically, when my router give a redirection to a function, this function wouldn't use a database var (DB) nil, isn't?

Thank for your answers !

**EDIT 2**
I red your answers and then, I edited my code like you asked with some adds. After init_SQL, DB isn't nil !

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    db "./database_sql"
    router "./router"
)

func main() {

    if db.Init_SQL() == true {

            if db.DB == nil {
                    fmt.Println("db.DB is nil !")
            }

            if router.Init_routes() == true {

                    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router.GetRouter())

            }
    }
}
```

So, now my 2 init functions return true on success and false on failure. I thought it could be an asynchronous problem, I made it like that to wait the end of each functions to continue my 'step by step'

Comment: I assume that "error opening database" does NOT print, correct?  There's no reason why you would get a failure on the DB.Prepare line other than Init_SQL failed to Ping() the db

Comment: Can you check if the global DB variable is set after `db.Init_SQL();`?

Comment: I suggest you printing out `DB` value after `db.Init_SQL()` and after `router.Init_routes()`, also before/after **every** function call you made in your calling stack, in this way you might have an idea when your `DB` get reset, or haven't been set at all.

Comment: Thank for your answers, I added "**EDIT 2**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is not idomatic to export a global var like that. Complex types should be  initialized by the runtime (which you are doing with `main()`), but retained globally from the runtime to control the disposal.

You are also missing a `db.Close()`.

I believe I ran I to the same issue with your pattern a few years ago when first using MySQL.  There is an oddness with the way one creates a local scoped pointer, and then assign it to a global var.  It is usually better to assign it directly to global var.  But I think the core issue is you need to assign the pointer to the pointer.

The pattern I use is to keep the testable database/sql `*DB` in the global state where I initialize it.  Why reinvent the wheel when the wheel works:

```
package main

import ( 
  ...
  "database/sql"

  "mypackage-that-inits-db/database"
)

var db *sql.DB

find main() {

  var err error
  db, err = database.Init_SQL(...params)
  if err != nil {
    ...
  }
  defer db.Close()

  InitUsers(db)
  InitStats(db)
  ...

  http.ListenAndServe(...)

  // now inject db global dependency in other code
  //

  globalStats := NewStatsEngine(db)
  globalStats.RecordUpdateToSomething(...)

  users := getUsers(db)

   ... etc

}
```

That's typically the pattern you see in other code.

Note the control over defer and Close, where it belongs here in caller.

#### Can't Test that easily

Also note that your code in other packages now becomes easily testable by creating a mock `sql.DB` object and injecting it into NewStatsEngine, getUsers, etc instead of having to mock a global var, test, tear down and setup again for test test, test, teardown, etc.  Also since Go 1.5, tests could be run concurrently so you'll even need to put a mutex.Lock around your global DB var if you leave your package like that.  Switching to a IoC pattern, like Dependency Injection which I demo'd in the code above, makes so much easier to test (and debug) your code.